# Decimal to binary Half-Precision IEEE 754 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I was only able to convert a decimal into a binary single-precision IEEE754, using the `struct.pack` module, or do the opposite (float16 or float32) using `numpy.frombuffer`

Is it possible to convert a decimal to a binary half precision floating point, using Numpy?

I need to print the result of the conversion, so if I type `"117.0"`, it should print `"0101011101010000"`

Comment: `np.float16('2.3')` works fine for me.  Can you clarify what you're asking? Perhaps show an example of what you're trying.

Comment: related: [Floating point to 16 bit Twos Complement Binary, Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31464022/4279)

Comment: `float16` method doesn't convert from base 10 to base 2. For example, I want 100.25 (base 10) to IEEE754 half precision in base 2, not base 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> if I type "117.0", it should print "0101011101010000"

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bin(np.float16(117.0).view('H'))[2:].zfill(16)
'0101011101010000'
```

[`.view('H')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) reinterprets the memory occupied by the `float16` value as an unsigned integer.

Comment: This solution works, thank you! I'll now try to understand your code

Comment: @Kaio: I recommend using Python REPL, to execute the code step by step and see the intermediate results. Also use `help()`, to see the corresponding docstrings e.g., `help(''.zfill)`

Comment: @jfs could you explain the view function used here a little bit, or maybe a link to the documentation

Answer (score 3):

The [`float16`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) method suggested by [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) has to be followed by the `tostring()` method to obtain the required binary representation:

```
data = numpy.float16(2.3).tostring()
```

Comment: If I run: `import numpy as np

b=np.float16(2.3).tostring()
print b` , it prints only a "?@", no base 2 numbers

Comment: The proposed solution provides the same type of result as the `struct.pack` does: A sequence of bytes. If you need a different output you have to make it clear in your question, preferably with examples.

Comment: I need to print the result of the conversion, so if I type "117.0", it should print "0101011101010000"

Comment: @Kaio: Ah, that's helpful; thanks. Please could you edit your question to add the example?  It sounds as though you want something like `'{:016b}'.format(struct.unpack('<H', np.float16('117.0').tobytes())[0])`, though there may be shorter ways of doing this.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Your solution would deserve to become the (accepted) answer.

Comment: @dlask: There are two good answers already! I like the `.view` approach, particularly.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I got a: `numpy.float16' object has no attribute 'tobytes'`

Comment: @Kaio: Yes, sorry, the `tobytes` method is new in NumPy 1.9; you're probably using an earlier version.  Use `tostring` instead.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yes, I'm using NumPy 1.8.2. Now your solution works too, thank you very much Mark!