# How to obtain the half precision floating point representation of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, half-precision-float

I want to obtain the binary representation of a variable `x` in half precision floating point representation. `x` can be anything (like -1.25 or 10 etc). I have tried quite a few things but can't really get this right.

I have tried making my own function but it doesn't work for all numbers. It's filled with bugs.

I have tried using struct but I don't really know much on how to use it.

```
var = pack('e', 0.25)
t = unpack('H',var)
bin(t[0] & 0xffff)
```

This doesn't seem to give correct representation.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451800/decimal-to-binary-half-precision-ieee-754-in-python): use `np.float16(var).tostring()`.

Comment: This seems helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444778/3377926

Comment: @TrevorKeller  `bin(np.float16(117.0).view('H'))[2:].zfill(16)` was just what I needed! Thanks